# How can I replace the text in JSON string with a userscript for Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, html, json, replace, userscripts

I want to create a user script for Greasemonkey in Firefox without using jQuery, which can replace old text by new text when the page of website is loaded.

HTML code:

```
..

window.app = profileBuilder({
..
    "page": {
        "btn": {
            "eye": "blue",
            "favorite_color": "blue",
            "gender": "male",
        },
    },
..
});

..
```

Replace "blue" of eye by "green", "blue" of favorite color by "red" and "male" by "female".

When the page will be loaded, I want to see, for instance Green (not Blue) for Eye and Female for Gender (not Male).

I guess I need to use functions next:

```
GM_getValue()
GM_setValue()
JSON.parse()
JSON.stringify()
```

PS: the code JSON is directly in the page and not in file (../code.json)

Userscript code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        nemrod Test
// @namespace   nemrod
// @include     http*://mywebsite.com/*
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==
var json = {"page": {"btn": {"eye": "blue","favorite_color": "blue","gender": "male",},},};
var stringified = JSON.stringify(json);
stringified = stringified.replace(/"eye": "blue"/gm, '"eye": "green"');
stringified = stringified.replace(/"favorite_color": "blue"/gm, '"favorite_color": "red"');
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(stringified);
```

It doesn't work

Can somebody help with the right code?

Comment: is this part of your script or page itself ?

Comment: What have you tried and why is it your guess that you need to use those functions?

Comment: @vishalsharma This part is on page itself.

Comment: @paul Because I looked on the web?

Comment: this is just an object so you can use **unsafeWindow.page.btn.eye = "green"**;

Comment: @vishalsharma Doesn't work, of course I enabled (grant         unsafeWindow) in my userscript

Answer (score 16):

First `stringify()` your JSON.

```
var stringified = JSON.stringify(json);
```

Next, use the `.replace()` JavaScript String function.

```
stringified = stringified.replace('"eye": "blue"', '"eye": "green"');
stringified = stringified.replace('"gender": "male"', '"gender": "female"');
```

Now `parse()` your JSON into an object.

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(stringified);
```

Now, you can use `jsonObject` for whatever you want.

EDIT: Use these lines instead of the previous `.replace()`s.

```
stringified = stringified.replace('"eye": "blue"', '"eye": "green"');
stringified = stringified.replace('"gender": "male"', '"gender": "female"');
```

Comment: Can I use a regex ? Like /"eye": "(d+)"/g replace "eye": "green", because if I have "favorite_color": "blue" we can see 2 time the same color.

Comment: You could but I think the `.replace()` String function is more straightforward right now since it is provided in JavaScript anyway. You could use RegEx too if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

more accurate procedure would be to use regular expression.

```
   stringified.replace(/"eyes":"blue"/gm, '"eyes":"blue"')
```

this way you know you're replacing the blue for eyes and not any blue appearing (like favorite color).
the 'g' & 'm' options for regular expression stands for global which will cause searching for all applicable matches (in case you have more than one 'eyes' in your json) and 'm' for multiline. in case your string is multilined.

Comment: I am not able to replace it like this

Answer (score 1):

First iteration - [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```js
var json = {"page": {"btn": {"eye": "blue","favorite_color": "blue","gender": "male"}}};

var replaceBy = {
  eye: function(value) {
    if (value == 'blue') {
      return 'green'
    }
  },
  favorite_color: function(value) {
    if(value == 'blue') {
      return 'red'
    }
  },
  gender: function(value) {
    if(value == 'male') {
      return 'female'
    }
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(json, function(key, value) {
  if(replaceBy[key]) {
    value = replaceBy[key](value)
  }
  return value
}))
```

Second iteration - be nice for **ES Harmony**

- add rule - adds strict comparison
- add matcher - adds any function that is responsible for data matching / replacing

```js
'use strict'

var json = {
  "page": {
    "btn": {
      "eye": "Blue",
      "favorite_color": "blue",
      "gender": "male"
    }
  }
};

class Replacer {
  constructor() {
    this.matchers = []
  }

  addRule(rule, source, destination) {
    this.matchers.push({
      type: rule,
      matcher: value => value == source ? destination : value
    })
    return this
  }

  addMatcher(type, matcher) {
    this.matchers.push({
      type: type,
      matcher: matcher
    })
    return this
  }

  getByType(type) {
    return this.matchers.find(matcher => matcher.type === type)
  }

  applyRuleFor(type, value) {
    if (this.getByType(type)) {
      return this.getByType(type).matcher(value)
    }
  }

  static replaceWith(replacer) {
    return (key, value) => {
      if (replacer.getByType(key)) {
        value = replacer.applyRuleFor(key, value)
      }
      return value
    }
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(json, Replacer.replaceWith(new Replacer()
  .addMatcher('eye', (value) => value.match(/blue/i) ? 'green' : value)
  .addRule('favorite_color', 'blue', 'red')
  .addRule('gender', 'male', 'female'))))
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSON` string manipulation can be done easily with  `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()`.

A sample example is given below:

```javascript
var tweet = '{ "event": { "type": "message_create", "message_create": { "target": { "recipient_id": "xx_xx" }, "message_data": { "text": "xxx_xxx" } } } }';

var obj = JSON.parse(tweet);
obj.event.message_create.target.recipient_id = Receiver;
obj.event.message_create.message_data.text = statusText;

var tweetString = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Now the `tweetString` has the updated `JSON` object.